# A more readable way of joining some lists with some lists returned by lapply in R

Tags: r, lapply

Say I want to create a list of four lists. The first two are manually defined, the second two are the result of lapply. So to be specific, I have these three items:

```
> list("a" = 1)
> list("b" = 1)
> lapply(1:2,FUN=function(i) { list("c"=i) }
```

And I want to combine them so that the output list is:

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$a
[1] 1


[[2]]
[[2]]$b
[1] 1


[[3]]
[[3]]$c
[1] 1


[[4]]
[[4]]$c
[1] 2
```

I can achieve it using the following:

```
> unlist(recursive=FALSE,
         list(
              list(list("a"=1),list("b"=1)),
              lapply(1:2,FUN = function(i) { list("c"=i) })
              )
         )
```

But all this lists of lists of lists business seems a bit verbose! I know I can of course just write a function to do this, but I'm wondering if there is a cleaner one liner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
c(list(list("a" = 1),list("b" = 1)),lapply(1:2,FUN=function(i) { list("c"=i) }))
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're objecting to that " lists of lists of lists business seems a bit verbose", are you unhappy that the output of lists is verbose, or the code of lists is verbose?

Which part(s) can be an atomic list, and which parts need to remain a list?  Do either of these address your concern?

```
c(
  rep("a", 1),
  rep("b", 1),
  rep("c", 2)
)

rep(
  c("a", "b", "c"), 
  c( 1 ,  1 ,  2 )
)
```

Both produce the atomic character vector:

```
[1] "a" "b" "c" "c"
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I need the output to match the exact data structure as specified in the question (for reasons currently not in my control). My comment about the verbose business, was regarding my own solution where I non-recursively unlisted a list of lists of lists